# NLTK CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader without using tokenizer

Tags: nltk

As for NLTK [CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.corpus.reader.html?highlight=plaintextcorpusreader#nltk.corpus.reader.plaintext.PlaintextCorpusReader), word tokenizing is set by default. I don't want to use any tokenizer with that reader. How can I apply this?

Comment: Simply write your own tokenizer and use the `word_tokenizer` parameter

Comment: I've solved with this.    tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r"^.*$")